# QuickSort fails with less items and works with more items on descending well sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I've written a `quickSort` method that I use to try to sort an array that is already nearly sorted - in reverse. So the quickSort tries to sort it in ascending order, while the array is already nearly sorted in descending order:

```
    private static void switchPlaces(int[] a, int i, int j) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }

    public static void quickSort(int[] a, int low, int high)  {
        int i = low;
        int j = high;
        int pivot = a[low];

        while (i <= j) {

            while (a[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }
            while (a[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }

            if (i <= j) {
                switchPlaces(a, i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        if (low < j) {
            quickSort(a, low, j);
        }
        if (i < high) {
            quickSort(a, i, high);
        }
    }
```

I use my custom method to generate such an array - 20% elements are greater than their previous elements.

However when I call qucksort on `100,000` long array I get stackoverflow error:

```
int[] a = generateArray(100_000);

quickSort(a, 0 , a.length - 1); //stackoverflow
```

Something that doesn't happen with `1,000,000` long array:

```
int[] a = generateArray(1_000_000);

quickSort(a, 0 , a.length - 1); //quickly works: all elements inside a are sorted
```

[image]

after `1_000_000` sort:

[image]

`a` at the start of `100_000` sort:

[image]

`a` at the start of `1_000_000` sort:

[image]

I don't understand why it works with larger array but not with smaller one.

**EDIT**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = generateArray(1_000_000);
        quickSort(a, 0 , a.length - 1);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int[] generateArray(int N) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int max = 1_000_000;
        int[] result = new int[N];

        int prev =  max - random.nextInt(100);
        result[0] = prev;
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            boolean toSort = random.nextInt(10) < 8;

            int number;
            if (toSort) {
                number = Math.max(0, prev - random(5, 10));
                prev = number;
            } else {
                number = prev + random(5, 10);
            }

            result[i] = number;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the first value in the range as the *pivot*, use the middle value.

If the data is already *fully* sorted, the result is that `quickSort(a, start, end)` recursively calls `quickSort(a, start + 1, end)`, so you get a recursive call stack depth equal to the array size, which will definitely cause **`StackOverflowError`** on larger data sets.

To illustrate, we can add a `print` statement to show `start` and `end` when method is called. To help even more, we can make the print statement show the call depth using indentation. If we then e.g. sort array `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`, we get (maxCallDepth = **9**):

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
0, 9
 1, 9
  2, 9
   3, 9
    4, 9
     5, 9
      6, 9
       7, 9
        8, 9
```

Similarly, if the data is *reversed* sorted, e.g. we sort array `{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0}`, we also get a very deep call stack (maxCallDepth = **9**):

```
{9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}
0, 9
 0, 8
  1, 8
   1, 7
    2, 7
     2, 6
      3, 6
       3, 5
        4, 5
```

By comparison, if we change the pivot to be the *middle value* of the range, the max call stack depth (i.e. max indentation) is greatly reduced (maxCallDepth = **3**, on both):

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
0, 9
 0, 3
  2, 3
 5, 9
  5, 6
  8, 9
```

```
{9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}
0, 9
 0, 4
  0, 1
  3, 4
 5, 9
  5, 6
  8, 9
```

***Conclusion:*** Change the code to use:

```java
int pivot = a[(start + end) / 2];
```

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduced it as well. Naturally, you are having a `StackOverflowError` because of the number of times `quickSort(...);` gets called recursively, which is not directly correlated with the number of elements on the array. Albeit, the bigger the array is, the more likely it is for the method `quickSort(...);` to get call more often recursively. However, it has more to do on how the elements are distributed on the array.

For instance:

```
  int[] a = new int [100_000];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        a[i] = i;

    quickSort(a, 0 , a.length - 1); //stackoverflow
```

will produce `java.lang.StackOverflowError` whereas

```
int[] a = new int [100_000];
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i+=2) {
    a[i] = i;
    a[i + 1] = 0;
}

quickSort(a, 0 , a.length - 1);
```

will not, even for an array of `new int [1000000];`.

Answer (score 1):

I did some analysis of your algorithm (as well as mine) and they both exhibited the same behavior.  I wrote my own data generator and everything worked fine.  That means that your data distribution for the lower array was such that it didn't sort efficiently for the chosen pivot.

So I put in some counters to count the max depth reached during the recursion process.  For the 1_000_000 value array the depth was in the low 100's (under 1000). for the 100_000 range value, the depth was near 15000 and caused a stack overflow.  The reason for this was the resulting distribution of data for your different sized arrays.

The algorithm I have always used was the one here which recommended to use the left most value as the pivot.

[image]

This excerpt from [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) talks about the choice of pivot.

> **Choice of pivot**
>
> In the very early versions of quicksort, the leftmost element of the partition would often be chosen as the pivot element. Unfortunately, this causes worst-case behavior on already sorted arrays, which is a rather common use-case. The problem was easily solved by choosing either a random index for the pivot, choosing the middle index of the partition or (especially for longer partitions) choosing the median of the first, middle and last element of the partition for the pivot (as recommended by Sedgewick).[18] This "median-of-three" rule counters the case of sorted (or reverse-sorted) input, and gives a better estimate of the optimal pivot (the true median) than selecting any single element, when no information about the ordering of the input is known.

By changing the pivot to  `arr[(p + r)/2]` everything worked much better.  This was also the final recommendation in  [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65135318/1552534)